# Sum of Digits Program not giving correct answer for negative number in c

Tags: c

```
    printf("Sum Digit Program\n");
int n,re, sum = 0;
    printf("Enter an integer n="); scanf("%d", &n);
while(n){
    re = n % 10;
    sum = sum + re;
    n = n / 10;
}
printf("Sum digit = %d", sum);
return 0;
}
```

I try this and it works well with positive integer but when I enter a negative integer like: -323 => -8
It's supposed to be -3+2+3 =2 not -3-2-3=-8
I try using abs function but it still doesn't work right

Comment: Look to me like you want the end of the while loop to be `n = abs(n/10);` That way the first time through you handle it as a -ve, and all the subsequent times it is treated as a positive.

Comment: Saying the sum of digits of -323 should be -3 + 2 + 3 is a bit of a stretch imo.  Are you sure that's really what you want?  Suppose I write it as -0323 (still in base 10), would you want the answer to change?  Mathematically it's nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

OP almost had it.  Simply treat MSDigit as signed.  All other digits, use `abs(rem)`.  Works for `INT_MIN`

```
printf("Sum Digit Program\n");
int sum = 0;
printf("Enter an integer n="); 
scanf("%d", &n);
while (n) {
  int re = n % 10;
  n = n / 10;
  sum += n ? abs(re) : re; // At MSDigit when n==0
}
printf("Sum digit = %d", sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you may use conditional operator to store the `sign` value like `int sign = (n >= 0 ? 1 : -1);` as shown below -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*
 * @brief   Logic for returning sum of digits
 */
int digi_sum(int n)
{
    int sign = (n >= 0 ? 1 : -1);
    int sum = 0;
    n *= sign;
    while (n)
    {
        if (n < 10)
            sum += (sign * (n % 10));
        else
            sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        printf("Sum: %d, n: %d\n", sum, n);
    }
    printf("sum: %d, n: %d\n", sum, n);
    return sum;
}
/*
 * @brief   Driver function
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num = -323;
    printf("Sum: %d\n", digi_sum(num));
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is to store the sign of the number into a separate variable and use it when `n < 10`.

Comment: Corner case: `n *= sign;` is UB when `n == INT_MIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Use **n=abs(n/10)** instead of **n=n/10**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
main()
{
printf("Sum Digit Program\n");
int n,re, sum = 0;
printf("Enter an integer n="); scanf("%d", &n);
while(n)
    {
    re = n % 10;
    sum = sum + re;
    n =abs(n/10);
    }
printf("Sum digit = %d", sum);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition to the first line of your loop to make sure that the `sum` so far is positive when `n < 10`, after that it will make the subtraction for the least digit if it has too. Then your loop should look like this:

```
while(n){
        if (abs(n) < 10) {
            sum = abs(sum);
        }
        re = n % 10;
        sum = sum + re;
        n = n / 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need a precondition for the first number.
with an if then else.
Solved
I changed the output to see the values

```
include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 int re,n;
 int sum =0 ;

 printf("Sum Digit Program \n");
 printf("Enter an integer n= "); 
 scanf("%d", &n);

 while(n)
 {
  if (abs(n) < 10) {
        sum = abs(sum);
  }       
 re= (n % 10);
 sum = sum + re; 
 n= n / 10; 

 printf ("\n  re =  %d , n=  %d \n",  re, n); 
 }   
 printf ("\n  sum=  %d \n",sum);
return 0;
}
```